# React Redux action payload not in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an action creator that I'm calling in componentWillMount, the return of that action payload is being assigned to state using setState. However, in componentDidMount I cannot access that property as the async call hasn't completed yet. What is the correct way to access this data in compoentDidMount?

```
//component
class Dashboard extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState(this.props.getUser());
  }

componentDidMount() {
    // this.state.user isn't available yet
}

render(){
  return(...);
}
}

//action
export function getUser() {
  return async function (dispatch) {
     const user = await axios.get(`${API_URL}user?token=${token}`);
     return dispatch({
      type: USER,
      payload: user,
     });
    } 
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios returns a promise and you have to wait until it resolves. Then dispatch the success action like this,

```
export function getUser() {
  return function (dispatch) {
     axios.get(`${API_URL}user?token=${token}`)
        .then(user => {
             return dispatch(getUserSuccess(user));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw error;
        });
    } 
  };

  export function getUserSuccess(user) {
    return {type: USER, payload: user};
  }
```

Also note that you need to have `mapStateToProps` so it brings the `user` to your component. Then you can access it using `this.props.user` within your component. It should be like this.

```
UserPage.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({getUser}, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserPage);
```

Finally you may access the user like this.

```
  render() {
    const {user} = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
        <div>user.name</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to do that, for example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (nextProps.user !== this.state.user) {
       this.setState({
           user: nextProps.user
       });
   }
}
```

now you can use `user` inside your component.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) you can find more information.